# If $\mu(A)\ne0$, is there always a $f\in L^p(\mu)$ with $\{f\ne0\}\subseteq A$ and $\mu(\{f\ne0\})\ne0$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ be a measure space and $p\in[1,\infty]$.

Are we able to show that if $A\in\mathcal A$ with $\mu(A)\ne0$, then there is a $f\in\mathcal L^p(\mu)$ with $\{f\ne0\}\subseteq A$ and $\mu\left(\{f\ne0\}\right)\ne0$?

If not, are we able to give a suitable condition on $\mu$ to ensure that the desired conclusion holds?

Comment: Well, take $f=1_A$?

Comment: If $\mu(A) < \infty$ take $1_A$. Otherwise, does the space have a set with finite positive measure?

Comment: @mrsamy Of course, I'm not assuming that $\mu$ is finite or $\mu(A)<\infty$.

Comment: @user251257 We can of course assume that $\mu$ is nontrivial. And I think we can also assume that there is a set with finite positive measure. But does the latter help?

Comment: I don't know what is the most general setting in which the statement is true, for sure it  works with $\sigma$-finite measure spaces. In full generallity if I am not wrong you can fix an element $a\in \Omega$ and define a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\{A\})$ is infinite if $A$ contains $a$ and $0$ otherwhise. In that case $\{ f\neq 0\}$ cannot be contain in $\{a\}$ for any $L^p$ function (or in any set containing $a$).

Comment: @0xbadf00d if the space is sigma finite, then it is trivial. Otherwise it is not true in general. Consider the algebra $\{\emptyset, X, X^C, \Omega\}$ and put some suitable measure on it

Comment: @AdrianPortilloFernández Can you provide an answer in the $\sigma$-finite case?

Comment: @user251257 I'm also interested in the $\sigma$-finite case. How do you argue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the space is $\sigma$-finite, say $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty X_i = \Omega$ with $\mu(X_i) < \infty$ and $X_i \subseteq X_{i+1}$, then
$$ \lim_{i\to \infty} \mu(X_i \cap A) = \mu(A) > 0.$$
That is, for sufficiently large $i$, $\mu(X_i \cap A)$ becomes positive and remains finite.

Comment: What if $\mu(A)=\infty$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d still the same proof. As $\mu(X_i \cap A) \le \mu(X_i) < \infty$.

Comment: I was worrying about $\mu(X_i\cap A)=0$, but for large enough $i$ that's excluded as well.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider the $\sigma-$algebra $\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}\}$ and the Lebesgue measure. Then for this space, $L^p = \{0\}$ because the only measurable functions on $\mathcal{A}$ are constants and $\int_\mathbb{R}|\alpha|^pdm <\infty$ iff $\alpha=0$. Thus $\{f\not=0\} = \emptyset$ for any $f\in L^p$.